# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'channel'

Tags: python, class, undefined

I'm trying to use this from git: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MPR121/blob/master/adafruit_mpr121.py

Inside the class it defines:

```
class MPR121_Channel:

def __init__(self, mpr121, channel):
    self._mpr121 = mpr121
    self._channel = channel
```

When I run an example code, based off: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MPR121/blob/master/examples/mpr121_simpletest.py

But add the line

```
mpr121_channel = adafruit_mpr121.MPR121_Channel(i2c)
```

so that I can access the variables in that class, it gives the error:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'channel'
```

I've edited to be:

```
mpr121_channel = adafruit_mpr121.MPR121_Channel(i2c, channel)
```

But now name 'channel' is undefined.

Please could someone help me work out where (and how) to define channel?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake in creating an object of that class. Could you provide more clarification as to which object are you creating ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try

mpr121 = adafruit_mpr121.MPR121_Channel(i2c)
make channel=None

Comment: I tried "mpr121_channel = adafruit_mpr121.MPR121_Channel(i2c, 1)" which works! I assume it is now only reading channel 1, but that will do for now

Comment: Now it's claiming i2c doesn't have the attribute "_read_register_bytes". It reads using the other class just fine! I'm so lost